# Cannot read property 'NaN' of undefined react js

Tags: reactjs

i keep geeting the error "Cannot read property 'NaN' of undefined" i think the .length is causing the problem cause i think the length is sometimes undefind and that's causing the NaN problem however i'm not sure how to fix this. this is my code

```
  const getApiData = async () => {
   setIsLoading(true);
  const response = await fetch(
    `https://api/find_similar?id=${_id}`      
  ).then((response) => response.json());
  setIsLoading(false);

  // update the state
  setData(response);
};

useEffect(() => {
getApiData();
// eslint-disable-next-line
}, []);

// this line is causing the problem
const preSaving = data[data?.length - 1].price - data[0].price
const saving = Math.round((preSaving + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100
// this line is causing the problem
const prePercentageSaving = ((1 - ( data[0].price / data[data?.length - 1].price )) *100)
const percentageSaving = Math.round((prePercentageSaving + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100
```

}

Comment: your `data` is undefined

Comment: Console logging the data can help you solve lot of things beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if the array is initialized first before accessing anything inside of it which leads to the error you are recieving.
Try this :

```
const preSaving = data.length ? data[data.length - 1].price - data[0].price : null;
```

Answer (score 2):

So if data is undefined, then in the line `data[data?.length - 1].price - data[0].price`
the following happens:
`data?.length // undefined`
`data?.length - 1 // NaN`
`data[data.length - 1] // Uncaught Type Error`

You could try initializing data as an empty array, which won't solve all problems but is probably a good idea anyways. Then
`data[data.length - 1]` becomes undefined (no Element exists in the array).
Therefore you will still run into a problem with `data[data.length - 1].price`. Basically you are trying to do computations on data you don't have.

So make sure to only do the computations once you have the data, e.g. move them into the setData function.
Alternativly check, if data exists and set them to a good default otherwise, e.g.
`const preSaving = data ? data[data?.length - 1].price - data[0].price : 0`

Answer (score 0):

I tried opening the link that was being fetched without the id filter

https://api/find_similar

But my browser said it couldn't find the page.

Also, when I'm fetching data, I like to set it to an empty useState first

```
const [myApi, setMyApi] = useState(null)
```

And then, within the useEffect, set the data to that API

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch(url).then(response => {return response.json()}).then(data => {setMyApi(data)})
}, [])
```